# OpenGL / Assimp oddity or error?

Tags: opengl, assimp

A friend and I are working on developing a game engine in C++. He doesn't live anywhere near me, so we use Dropbox to sync our files. I opened his project to test his code, and I kept getting errors saying that the program could not start with an error that stated "This application could not start. 0xc015002." I used a dependency walker to find that ILUT.dll was causing some issues. I have done just about everything suggested on most forums to make ILUT work, and I have not had any success. I've re-downloaded it, put the DLL just about everywhere I could, and I still had issues. We then tried to compile it without Assimp, and the program compiled without errors. This was not the end of our problems though. I made a class to create a primitive cube using OpenGL. When I tested it out, there was no cube on the screen. I had my friend test the program out, and to our surprise, there was a perfectly rendered cube on his screen. So I'm honestly not sure where things could possibly be going wrong. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this long question. I'll be happy to provide anyone with necessary info needed to help with this question!

My OpenGL version is 4.2. He has an nVidia graphics card, and I have an AMD Radeon graphics card. We are using Visual Studios 2012 as our IDE.

Comment: "something like..." error reports are going to get you answers "something like..." useless answers =)  Can you capture the exact error along with what you've done to find differences between your machine and his?  I know it's frustrating when something behind the scenes is stopping your work, precision is the best way to get help.

Comment: The error i received was "The application was unable to start correctly 0xc0150002". That's about all it told me, and the compiler had some errors with glew32, DevIL, and ILUT about the modules being built without symbols. The real difference between his machine and mine that we could spot was that he has an nVidia graphics card and I have an AMD Radeon graphics card. Our project settings are the same, all the DLL files are where they should be, and we both have all the necessary re-distributable packs for VS. Thank you for replying though! I hope that's enough info.

Comment: Im sorry, but there is no way anyone could possibly figure out your issue with the information provided.

Comment: What information would you need me to provide?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I had to do. I had to get the Assimp SDK, replaced the include files with the ones supplied by the SDK, and things started to work perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted.